# Boundary Condition defined on a Parallel Vector

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am given the following equation

$au_x+bu_y = 1$ for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
In addition, $u(s \vec{r}) = \sin(s)$ where $s\in \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to find for which vectors $\vec{r}$ there exists a unique solution.

I went about by trying to find a solution for $u(x,t)$ utilizing the method of characteristics. I defined $X'(s) = b $ and $Y'(s) = a$. Then, I know that $Z'(s) = u'(X(s),Y(s)) = bu_x + au_y = 1$. I then integrated with respect to $s$ to get 
$Z(s) = u(X(0),Y(0)) + s$. I am not sure where to continue from here. I know $u$ is not constant with respect to the characteristic curve $(X(s),Y(s))$ and in fact changes with respect to $s$ at a constant rate. I am not sure how to use the defined boundary condition, where it prescribes the value of $u$ on a line parallel to $\vec{r}$.